# Trouble converting a Stata command for survey design declaration to R - svydesign

Tags: r, stata, survey

I am working on the INCA3 nutrition dataset. To be analyzed, a survey declaration must be performed. It is explained in this file:
https://static.data.gouv.fr/resources/donnees-de-consommations-et-habitudes-alimentaires-de-letude-inca-3/20210128-192916/notice-utilisateurs-donnees-inca3-data.gouv-english.pdf

In particular, for the dataset I am interested in, the following Stata command is provided (p. 69):

```
svyset zae [pweight=pond_indiv_adu_pop3], ///
    strata(strate) fpc(fpc1) vce(linearized) singleunit(scaled) ///
    || NOMEN, fpc(fpc2) || NOIND, fpc(fpc3)
```

Unfortunately, I do not use Stata and have not worked with this type of survey before. I am working with R and found the `survey` package, with the corresponding `svydesign` command. Here is my attempt at reproducing the code in R:

```
svydesign(id=~zae+NOMEN+NOIND,
          strata=~strate,
          weights=~pond_indiv_adu_pop3,
          fpc=~fpc1+fpc2+fpc3,
          data=conso_alim)
```

Unfortunately, it is not working, as I obtain the following error:

`` Error in (function (object, ...)  : missing values in `weights' ``

Is there anything wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message suggested, you have missing values in weights variable: `pond_indiv_adu_pop3`. You could try to use a subset of data:

```
svydesign(id = ~zae + NOMEN + NOIND,
          strata = ~strate,
          weights = ~pond_indiv_adu_pop3,
          fpc = ~fpc1 + fpc2 + fpc3,
          data=subset(conso_alim, !is.na(pond_indiv_adu_pop3))
```

I am not sure if this will fix your problem without a reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks! I solved the problem by using a similar solution data=conso_alim[!is.na(conso_alim$pond_indiv_adu_pop3),] and it seems to work (the problem was due to the coexistence of different groups, i.e., adults and children, in the dataset.

Are the Stata arguments vce(linearized) singleunit(scaled) required in a way though?

Comment: one note, to replicate stata's `singleunit(scaled)` option, i think you'll also want to set `options(survey.lonely.psu='ajdust')`  ...  stata's [singleunit](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/svysvyset.pdf) corresponds to the R survey package's [lonely psu](http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/exmample-lonely.html)